# Adding UIView to keyWindow's base view doesn't apply transform?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm attempting to add a UIView to the base view of the view hierarchy like so:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow
UIView *baseView = [windows.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[baseView addSubView:myView];
```

Works great, however, when in landscape mode or while rotating it doesn't rotate the view correctly.  There is indeed a transform applied to the base view but it doesn't appear to be the correct one?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Autoresize Masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask). This property will tell the view how to resize itself with respect to its superview when the superview changes its frame.

For example, the following setting will keep the size fixed.

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the issue. The base view I'm adding the view to is the one directly at the top of the view hierarchy to achieve a custom presentViewController animation. The transform on the base view looks fine when I print it out with NSLog() but when I add the subview to it, it doesn't transform the subview?